# PowerMock `thenReturn` doesn't return expected data for mocked static method?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, powermock

I am able to tun my test but it fails. The problem is, mocked method is still returning wrong data. This is my method that I want to test it:

```
fun getTextByLanguage(list: List<TitleModel>) : String {
    val deviceLanguage = Locale.getDefault().language

    var default = ""
    for (item in list) {
        if (item.culture.contains(deviceLanguage, true)) return item.value
        if (item.culture.contains("en", true)) default = item.value
    }

    return default
```

}

And this is how I am testing the method:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import java.util.Locale

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(Locale::class)
class AppConfigUtilityByPowerMockTest {

    @Test
    fun `getTextByLanguage, test en`() {
        mockStatic(Locale::class.java)
        val mockedLocal = mock(Locale::class.java)
        `when`(Locale.getDefault()).thenReturn(mockedLocal)
        `when`(mockedLocal.language).thenReturn("en")

        val list = listOf(TitleModel("en-ca", "Home"), TitleModel("fr-ca", "HomeFr"))
        val actual = getTextByLanguage(list)

        assertEquals("Home", actual)
    }

    @Test
    fun `getTextByLanguage, test fr`() {
        mockStatic(Locale::class.java)
        val mockedLocal = mock(Locale::class.java)
        `when`(Locale.getDefault()).thenReturn(mockedLocal)
        `when`(mockedLocal.language).thenReturn("fr")

        val list = listOf(TitleModel("en-ca", "Home"), TitleModel("fr-ca", "HomeFr"))
        val actual = getTextByLanguage(list)

        assertEquals("HomeFr", actual)
    }
}
```

The first test cases without problem but the second one fails. This is the out put:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<Home[Fr]> but was:<Home[]>
Expected :HomeFr
Actual   :Home
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to answer the question is to get rid of `Local` class from the method and do stuff in Kotlin way. So, what I did is to change my original method like this:

```
fun getTextByLanguage(list: List<TitleModel>, deviceLanguage: String = getDeviceLanguage()) : String {
    var default = ""
    for (item in list) {
        if (item.culture.contains(deviceLanguage, true)) return item.value
        if (item.culture.contains("en", true)) default = item.value
    }

    return default
}

fun getDeviceLanguage(): String {
    return Locale.getDefault().language
}
```

Now my test class looks like this:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import java.util.Locale

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(Locale::class)
class AppConfigUtilityByPowerMockTest {

    @Test
    fun `getTextByLanguage, test en`() {
        val list = listOf(TitleModel("en-ca", "Home"), TitleModel("fr-ca", "HomeFr"))
        val actual = getTextByLanguage(list, "en")

        assertEquals("Home", actual)
    }

    @Test
    fun `getTextByLanguage, test fr`() {
        val list = listOf(TitleModel("en-ca", "Home"), TitleModel("fr-ca", "HomeFr"))
        val actual = getTextByLanguage(list, "fr")

        assertEquals("HomeFr", actual)
    }
}
```

Although my test passes, I am still willing to see your recommendation and down to accept your answer to my question.